# How to use bootstrap in Meteor?

Tags: twitter-bootstrap, meteor

I'm trying to use bootstrap in meteor 1.0.
I add bootstrap package in meteor with this command: "meteor add bootstrap".
But it can't works for me correctly.

I need one row with two columns.
This is my html:

```
    <head>
    <meta charset="utf-8">
    <title>Аггрегатор новостей</title>
</head>

<body>
<div class="container-fluid">
    <div class="row">
        <div class="col-md-6">.col-md-6</div>
        <div class="col-md-6">.col-md-6</div>
    </div>
</div>
</body>
```

But I see two rows with 100% width. Wherein container or container-fluid  works, I see this is one the screen. 
What is the problem?
I need to link bootstrap.css in header? But Meteor do this automatically IMHO.

Thank you.

Comment: For Meteor 1.3+ check this solution: http://stackoverflow.com/a/37333520/276311

Answer (score 23, accepted):

By using `meteor add bootstrap` you are actually adding Bootstrap 2.3, which does not know the `col-md-x` classes. Either switch to using Bootstrap 3 using `meteor add twbs:bootstrap` which will install the official Bootstrap framework (v3) or adjust your code to

```
<div class="span6">span4</div>
```

Personally, I prefer using Bootstrap 3 instead of the core bootstrap package coming with Meteor core. Also, the boostrap package provided by MDG is [marked as deprecated](https://github.com/meteor/meteor/tree/devel/packages/deprecated).

Comment: Yes, this work for me! Thank you. I don't understand why in Meteor by default using older bootstrap. With JQuery we have same situation?

Comment: I think Bootstrap was added in the early days to have an easy way to make things a bit more pretty (also 3 wasn't out then). As Styling is no core feature it continued to be around but it has no priority and MDG does not waste resources on maintaining it. jQuery is at 1.11.0 and just a little behind.

Answer (score 15):

I recommend installing the official Twitter Bootstrap supported package:

```
meteor add twbs:bootstrap
```

See their [GitHub](https://github.com/twbs/bootstrap) for more details

Comment: Is there a guide to installing this package? Adding the package to Meteor does not seem to add the files... I know with other bootstrap packages there is an install procedure to render the files the first time.

Answer (score 10):

Starting from Meteor 1.3 which offers first-class **npm** support, the recommended approach is to install Bootstrap directly from npm.

```
$ meteor npm install --save bootstrap
```

(This also saves `bootstrap` in your `package.json` file so someone else who checks out your app can install it with `meteor npm install`.)

Then, in any client-side JS file (e.g. `/client/main.js`):

```
import 'bootstrap';
import 'bootstrap/dist/css/bootstrap.css';
import 'bootstrap/dist/css/bootstrap-theme.css';
```

If you're interested in more customized Bootstrap installs using SASS/SCSS, etc. check out **[this post](https://stackoverflow.com/a/37333520/586086)**.

Answer (score 2):

Have you tried with other package? For example with : https://atmospherejs.com/mizzao/bootstrap-3

I think that Meteor has dropped core Bootstrap package.

Comment: No worries -- now there is official Bootstrap support for Meteor! (see my answer)