# How use bootstrap via NPM in Meteor 1.3?

Tags: twitter-bootstrap, meteor, npm

It is my understanding that Meteor 1.3 favors *npm* packages over *Meteor / atmosphere* packages.

I tried to add  [Bootstrap](https://www.npmjs.com/package/bootstrap) to my project via `meteor npm install bootstrap`. Then I added a couple divs with classes `row` and `col-md-3` to test it was working and I did not see what I was expecting (I did not see the grid layout). I created those divs inside the `body` tag, which is declared on a file called `./imports/ui/body.html`. Maybe I'm missing an `import {Bootstrap} from 'meteor/bootstrap'`, `import {bootstrap} from 'bootstrap'` (which I tried, with no success) or similar or an `import '../../node_modules/bootstrap/somefile'`.

I tried `meteor add twbs:bootstrap` and the app worked as expected (proper grid layout for those `col-md-3`).

[This thread](https://forums.meteor.com/t/meteor-1-3-modules-when-to-use-a-meteor-package-vs-an-npm-package/16325/9) recommends using NPM. Maybe I missed something important in order to make it work via NPM with meteor 1.3?

My HTML code has nothing special (and worked when adding the meteor package twbs:bootstrap). The only quirk is that the HTML code is in a file in the `imports/` directory, so probably I missed something important about the [loading process](http://guide.meteor.com/1.3-migration.html).

Edits after seeing @loger9 and @benjaminos answers.

I did `meteor npm install --save bootstrap` and got a new node_modules directory. Just in case I run `npm install` and `meteor` again, to force any processes carried out on startup. *body.html* and *body.js* live in `imports/ui`. *body.html* is

```
<body>
  <div class="container page-wrap">

    <div class="page-header">
      <h1>A title</h1>
    </div>

    <div class="row">
      <div class="col-md-3" style="background: red;">
        Lorem Ipsum
      </div>

      <div class="col-md-3" style="background: lavenderblush;">
        Lorem Ipsum
      </div>
    </div>
  </div>

</body>
```

and *body.js* includes

```
import '../../node_modules/bootstrap/dist/css/bootstrap.min.css';

import './body.html';
```

But it complains it can not find the module `../../node_modules/bootstrap/dist/css/bootstrap.min.css` (if I cd to the imports/ui dir and from there I cat ../../node_modules/bootstrap/dist/css/bootstrap.min.css I see the file, so it doesn't look like  problem with that path being incorrect) and won't display anything.

Adding `import bootstrap from 'bootstrap'` seems to have no effect. *client/main.js* does also `import '../imports/ui/body.js';`

I actually know that this should be as easy as loger9 points out in their answer, but for some reason I can not get this to work.

Comment: Actually, I have no problem importing if I have the CSS on the /import directory. It seems that the /node_modules is "unreachable to me via import "...";

Comment: Also, I just found and decided to play around [this tutorial](http://www.angular-meteor.com/tutorials/socially/angular1/css-less-and-bootstrap) and just doing `meteor npm install bootstrap4-webpack-package --save` and adding `import 'bootstrap4-webpack-package';` on client/main.js gets it working. I dont know where I turned the wrong corner with my other project.

Answer (score 10):

I found the solution in this [Sergio Tapia's blog post](https://github.com/sergiotapia/sergiotapia.github.io/blob/master/_posts/2016-06-13-how-to-use-twitter-bootstrap-from-npm-in-your-meteor-application.markdown). It works on Meteor 1.3.2.2 or greater. These are the steps that worked for me (with **SASS/SCSS** support):

## Installing

```
meteor add fourseven:scss
meteor npm install bootstrap-sass --save
```

## Import to your code

- **`client/main.scss`** (note the .scss extension):

  ```css
  @import "{}/node_modules/bootstrap-sass/assets/stylesheets/_bootstrap.scss";
  ```
- **`client/main.js`**:

  ```
  import 'bootstrap-sass';
  ```

### Workaround for Glyphicons

The only solution I found for the **Glyphicons** font was to copy the fonts folder to `public/`:

```
cp -avr node_modules/bootstrap-sass/assets/fonts public/
```

Note how it is loaded in Meteor (`/fonts/bootstrap`, i.e., it needs to be in the public folder):

```css
@font-face {
  font-family: 'Glyphicons Halflings';
  src: url("/fonts/bootstrap/glyphicons-halflings-regular.eot");
  src: url("/fonts/bootstrap/glyphicons-halflings-regular.eot?") format("embedded-opentype"), url("/fonts/bootstrap/glyphicons-halflings-regular.woff2") format("woff2"), url("/fonts/bootstrap/glyphicons-halflings-regular.woff") format("woff"), url("/fonts/bootstrap/glyphicons-halflings-regular.ttf") format("truetype"), url("/fonts/bootstrap/glyphicons-halflings-regular.svg") format("svg");
}
```

---

## Optional step: Autoprefixer

Per [fourseven:scss](https://github.com/fourseven/meteor-scss), autoprefixer should preferably be installed as a separate plugin:

```
# optional
meteor remove standard-minifier-css
meteor add seba:minifiers-autoprefixer
```

Comment: Thanks. I'll have to make some time to check this. I decided to go with the meteor package, instead of the npm a long time ago, but this is useful information, for future reference. I'll upvote when I have had some time to check it. Thanks again.

Comment: The link above is broken, an updated blog post is here:
http://sergiotapia.me/meteor/bootstrap/npm/2016/06/13/how-to-use-twitter-bootstrap-from-npm-in-your-meteor-application.html

Comment: set the $icon-font-path before importing _bootstrap.scss seems to make the job...

$icon-font-path: '/node_modules/bootstrap-sass/assets/fonts/bootstrap/' !default;

Answer (score 9):

First you have to install bootstrap via npm:

`meteor npm install --save bootstrap` or same thing with `bootstrap-sass` if you want the sass version (my personal choice).

**If you installed the standard version**

You have to import the CSS file from the package in, for example, your `imports/startup/client/index.js` file, to ensure it will be loaded on client startup.

**If you installed ´bootstrap-sass´**

You can just make a ´main.scss´ file and point to `boostrap.scss` in the package( it should be in ´/node_modules/bootstrap-sass/assets/stylesheets/bootstrap.scss´).

So it would look like this.

client/main.scss

```
@import "../../node_modules/bootstrap-sass/assets/stylesheets/bootstrap";
```

This has added benefits. You can keep piling up scss from anywhere in this file, and control css load order. For example, you can make a sass directory in imports, make an index.sass file and then add it in main.scss. In my opinion it's very neat.

**How do you load the JS then?**

`import bootstrap from 'bootstrap'`
or
`import bootstrap from 'bootstrap-sass'`

That's how you import npm packages.

**EDIT:** Apparently this wasn't working for everyone, but in Meteor 1.3.2.2 they seem to have fixed this. Now you can (really) import sass and less files from npm packages.

`@import '{}/node_modules/bootstrap-sass/assets/stylesheets/_bootstrap.scss';`

Importing it like this should do the trick now.

Comment: +1. I know this should be the way to go, but I could not make it work. I edited my question to give more details and show code. Maybe I missed something somewhere else...

Comment: I saw your comment where you used `boostrap4-webpack-package`, but I can't answer there yet (not enough rep). That's actually pretty neat. That package is built with Webpack, which adds html and css to the js file, so that Meteor loads it like any other package so in a way it's cheating. The official package just doesn't do this, you have to import any html or css by hand. I know, it sucks :/.

Comment: You should check where you are importing the CSS, you are importing the CSS in a JS, is that in `client/`? The import won't load CSS or HTML, only JS, like `bootstrap.js`, giving you the global var `bootstrap`. EDIT: I saw you are trying to use this in `../import/ui/body.js`, you could try to import in it `client/main.js`, since it will load always anyway.

Comment: Thanks but o luck. I just created a brand new meteor project, run the `meteor npm install --save bootstrap` command switched the body's html to what can be seen in my question and tried both `import bootstrap from 'bootstrap'` @ /client/main.js and `import '../node_modules/bootstrap/dist/css/bootstrap.min.css';` from the same place. I can't see the proper grid layout. The first import seems to have no effect. For the second one I get "cannot find module". I don't understand what I'm doing wrong. This should be as simple as ABC.

Comment: By default Meteor does **not** import scss files. You need to install a package for this to happen. `meteor install fourseven:scss` for example will make the scss example work from this answer.